# Neighborhoods and Metric Spaces in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In my analysis class, we are looking at metric spaces and topologies.  We were asked to prove the following two theorems.  I believe I have the first one completed, but am somewhat confused by the second one; it seems like it should just "follow" from the first one, but I don't know how to rigorously show this:

1)  Prove that in a metric space, a set $N$ is a neighborhood of $a$ iff there exists a real number $\epsilon > 0$ such that the $B_\epsilon(a)\subset N$

2)  Prove that in a metric space, a set $N$ is a neighborhood of $a$ iff there exists a real number $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x \in N$ for any $x \in X$ such that $\rho(x,a)<\epsilon$

For #1, I have this:

Let $\epsilon\in R$ such that $\epsilon>0$ and $B_\epsilon(a)\subset N$ for some set $N$ and some point $a$.  $B_\epsilon(a)$ is an open ball contain $a$ and thus is an open set, i.e. $a\in B_\epsilon(a)$, thus by definition $N$ is a neighborhood of $a$
Now, let $N$ be a neighborhood of $a$. Then there exists an open set $U$ such that $a\in U$ and $U\subset N$.  By a previous theorem (which we proved, namely "a set is open in metric topology iff it is a union of open balls", $U$ must be a union of open balls, and thus $a$ must be contained in one of those balls, call it $B_r(z)$. Now, consider $B_{r-\rho(z-a)}$, a ball centered at $a$ with radius smaller than the distance from $a$ to $z$.  Note that $B_r(z)\subset U$ since it is in the union that forms $U$.  Thus, $B_{r-\rho(z-a)}\subset B_r(z)\subset U \subset N$.  So choose $\epsilon=r-\rho(z-a)$.  The there exists a real number $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(a) \subset N$.

I have no idea if it is correct, and I have no idea how to begin on #2.  The class doesn't have a textbook, and the professor posts notes but they are very blunt with only definitions and theorems (and not examples), and there are also many typos that he doesn't catch.  Any comments on my solution to #1 would be appreciated, and anything you can provide for #2 would be of immense help; we never discussed anything in class about epsilons, nor is there anything in his online notes about it either.

Comment: 2 is just a reformulation of 1. All $x$ with $\rho(x,a) < \epsilon$ is exactly the set $B_\epsilon(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

The text for the analysis course I took gives the following definition of a *neighborhood* (or an *open neighborhood* - also sorry that the definition is a bit long, but this is how it is given in my text authored by a professor of the university, and I didn't want to stray from the exact text):

**Definition:**  Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. We say the set $V\subset X$ is *open* if (and only if) for every $x\in X$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subset V$. A set $E\subset X$ is *closed* if (and only if) the compliment $E^{c}=X\big\backslash E$ is open. When the ambient space is not clear from context we say $V$ is open in $X$ and $E$ is closed in $X$. Furthermore, if $x\in V$ and $V$ is open, then we say that $V$ is an *open neighborhood* of $x$ (or sometimes just a *neighborhood* of $x$).

**//Proof:** Consider the metric space $(X,d)$ (i.e. from your work $(X,\rho)$). Supposing $N\subset X$ is a neighborhood $x$ directly implies by definition that for every $x\in N$ there exists some open ball $B(x,\delta)\subset N\subset X$ of radius $\delta>0$ around $x\in X$, and hence this direction is trivial.

Conversely, take $N\subset X$ and for $x\in N$ take an open ball $B(x, \delta')\subset N\subset X$. Now, $x\in B(x,\delta')$ trivially; moreover, we also note that $B(x,\delta')\subset N$ is an open set since for every $y\in B(x,\delta')$ there exists a $0<\widetilde{\delta}\leq\delta'$ such that $B(y,\widetilde{\delta})\subset B(x,\delta')\subset N\subset X$. Set $\widetilde{\delta}=\delta'-d(x,y)$, and take $z\in B(y,\widetilde{\delta})$. Then we have that:

$d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)<d(x,y)+\widetilde{\delta}=d(x,y)+\delta'-d(x,y)=\delta'$.

So $d(x,z)<\delta'$ yielding $z\in B(x,\delta')$ for every $z\in B(y,\widetilde{\delta})$. This proves the that $B(x,\delta')$ is open. I included this since you mentioned you didn't have a textbook, etc. Returning to  the proof, when $x\in N$ we have that there is an open (set) ball $B(x,\delta')\subset N$. Taking the union of these open (sets) balls yields an open set overall, so $N$ must be open. Therefore we conclude that since $x\in N$ and $N$ is open, we have the $N$ is an (open) neighborhood of $x$. Since statement (2) is an equivalent form of the statement we proved here, i.e. (1) holds if, and only if (2) holds, we have that (2) must also be true and we are done.$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\square$

Should you want to prove (2) independently, repeat the same procedure as the proof above, except recall the definition of an open ball in a metric space:

**Definition:** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in X$ and $\delta>0$. Then define the *open ball*, or simply a *ball*, of radius $\delta$ around $x$ as $B(x,\delta):=\big\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\delta\big\}$.

In your case treat $d(x,y)$ as $\rho(x,a)$, and proceed. Overall they are equivalent statements, so you will get very similar results. I hope this helps, as I tried to do things much more rigorously since you mentioned the lack of materials to prepare with.

Comment: By the way, where I proved that an open ball in a metric space is open, you can skip that part since any $x\in N$ implies there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subset N$, so $N$ must be open in this case. Like I said, I figured to include more since you mentioned you didn't have much to go from. Best of luck to you.